Calculate error for an arbitrary projection matrix
I am attempting to find the best linear projection from a small set of $r,g,b$ coordinates to a $u, v$ coordinate space with the following characteristics:

$ 0 \le u \le 1 $
$ 0 \le v \le 1 $
The resulting points in $u, v$ space tend to be distributed as uniformly as possible.
Projective error is minimized.

1 and 2 are trivial in the linear programming problem I've constructed. I have successfully represented 3 by manually choosing four marker points and, as appropriate, minimizing or maximizing their coordinate values to tend to be pulled toward the corners of the $u,v$ coordinate space.
4 is trickier. I understand intuitively that it overlaps with 3, because in the worst case the $r,g,b$ locus would project to a line in $u,v$ space;  and so I expect to need to write some optimization objective with a weight.
The input $r, g, b$ points are known as
      [[  0,   0,   0],
       [255, 255, 255],
       [120, 136,  97],
       [135, 129,  86],
       [ 93,  67,  31],
       [242, 239, 186],
       [247, 207, 202],
       [203, 167, 119],
       [246, 207, 179],
       [204, 119,  34],
       [250, 245, 231],
       [235, 214, 154],
       [ 39,  28,  19],
       [103,  50,  26],
       [244, 198, 166],
       [124, 138, 104],
       [255, 191, 104],
       [ 90,  67, 100],
       [ 59,  42,  66],
       [ 75,  53,  69],
       [203, 151,  53]])

So far the best projection I have produced is
[[-0.00041426  0.00584914]
 [ 0.00854942 -0.01107361]
 [-0.00507021  0.00914604]
 [-0.         -0.        ]]

That last row was an attempt to represent this as a homogeneous affine transformation, but it solved to 0 (probably because one of the input points is 0,0,0).
The projected corners given this solution become
[[0.         0.        ]
 [0.02850607 0.69909461]
 [1.         0.32765884]
 [0.78156051 1.        ]]

and all of the projected output points in the $u,v$ coordinate space are
      [[0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.78156051, 1.        ],
       [0.62119884, 0.08305154],
       [0.61091132, 0.14769742],
       [0.37710809, 0.0855652 ],
       [1.        , 0.47006215],
       [0.6432238 , 1.        ],
       [0.74030235, 0.42646095],
       [0.760253  , 0.78379192],
       [0.76048415, 0.18642987],
       [0.81982277, 0.86198543],
       [0.95141119, 0.41328512],
       [0.12689345, 0.09183007],
       [0.25297639, 0.28657773],
       [0.75004953, 0.7528576 ],
       [0.60114913, 0.14832315],
       [1.        , 0.32765884],
       [0.02850607, 0.69909461],
       [0.        , 0.4836462 ],
       [0.07220478, 0.48286082],
       [0.93814578, 0.        ]])

My central question is - when creating such a projection, we can imagine the $r,g,b$ locus to project onto a $u,v$ plane; but since the input locus is not coplanar, in addition to the known $u,v$ coordinates there will be a third implicit dimension $w$ as the distance from this plane, and that $w$ is an error term. How do we either explicitly calculate or implicitly minimize that term given some intermediate solution for the 4x2 projection matrix? I think part of the problem is that the projection matrix doesn't actually define an $r,g,b$ plane, but only a normal vector in $r,g,b$ space.

@whpowell96 If I understand correctly, this could only be represented as such if $B$ (the $u,v$ output) is known ahead of time, but it is not.
